# How to get date of registration?

Tags: django, django-authentication

How to get date of registration? What is the name of this field? I use django-registration. I don't see this in the documentation

```
User.objects.filter(date_of_registration_field__lt = my_date)
```

Answer (score 21):

> [`date_joined`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.date_joined)
>
> A datetime designating when the account was
> created. Is set to the current date/time by default when the account
> is created.